# ReflectionException after upgrading from laravel 4.2 upto 5.1.11 in a checkout of 5.2.23

Tags: php, laravel

`ReflectionException in Route.php line 264: Class App\Http\Controllers     \HomeController does not exist`

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', array(
  'as' => 'home',
  'uses' => 'HomeController@index',
));`
```

Interestingly, if I declare url like below, this error goes away

```
Route::get('/', function(){
  $obj = new HomeController();
  return $obj->index();
});
```

Comment: Is your HomeController in the namespace App\Http\Controllers?

Comment: I am not using any namespace directive in the HomeController.php file. In RouteserviceProvider.php class, protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers' is declared, I guess that puts my Homecontroller in the namespace you asked.

Comment: Paste a snippet from your HomeController please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are having namespace issues.

To get started, simply set your $namespace to:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

And then:

1. Make sure your `HomeController` in the `App\Http\Controllers` directory,
2. The `HomeController` starts with the following:

.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
```

Comment: It worked! Wonderful ! Does it mean, I have to use namespace both in RoterServiceProvider.php and in all Controllers?

Comment: The namespace in the Service Provider is telling the router.php file where to look for your files, so you can basically not open that file again. The important bit, moving forward, is making sure your new controllers have namespaces similar to HomeController.

Comment: There is a problem here, See The Controller Class I want to extend is in app\http\Controllers folder. Here the Controller class is extending BaseController class. But by writting, use Illuminate\Routing\Controller; Aren't you making it use the frameworks core Controller class directly? Is that ok?

Comment: It depends, if you want to extend your own controller, swap the `use` statement to point to your local copy instead. I feel like you need a deeper understanding of namespaces. https://laracasts.com/lessons/namespacing-primer is an excellent start - if you haven't signed up to laracasts, I recommend you do

Comment: the problem is , I am not being able to point to the controller I want.Whenever I am trying, my app is saying that it does not exist! But, it does!!ok , I will read your provided link first then.

Comment: Your own base controller should be in the same directory as the HomeController and have the same name space (App\Http\Controllers). If still not appearing, run a composer dumpautoload

Comment: All is in right place and this error is gone now. The problem was al about namespace. Laravel5.2 seems a little weired.

Comment: Namespaces have been in laravel for at least a few (if not all) versions. If you are going to do php dev, it won't hurt to get used to them. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Create the controller file using command line:

```
php artisan make:controller HomeController
```

open the controller file and check the namespace is correct.

In Routes:

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
```

This will redirect to the 'index' function inside 'HomeController'.

Comment: The HomeController exists according to the question - by running the make:controller command you are potentially overwriting the existing file (depending on how laravel handles existing files)

Comment: @Chris i am just giving the complete flow from creating a controller.

Comment: I understand but I feel it may at best, misleading, at worst, destructive

Comment: @Chris is right I think, but I also understand the idea that Sunil S Nair just wants me to start it afresh and then overright my functions in the controller again. Its arite, thank u so much both of you.